# Sending Hex String using WriteValue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, nsdata, core-bluetooth

I've been creating an app using XCode and Swift to connect to a bluetooth device (that has a LED colour strip connected to it) and I have written a piece of code that will make it change colour.

Using a bluetooth sniffer, I know that I need to send the value of '52130056FF000000AA' which would make it change to red, in this example. Here's a snippet of the code I have already. Characteristicx is defined before this code.

```
let data: NSData = "52130056FF000000AA".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: characteristicx, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)
```

This code converts the hex string given to this, which I do not want to send.
'<35323133 30303536 46463030 30303030 4141>'

So, the question is, **How do I get Swift to send just the 52130056FF000000AA to the BLE device and not the converted string?** The issue here is that the writeValue command requires NSData (as far as I can see) and I'm not sure how to use a plain hex string as the data to send in NSData form.

Hope someone can help with this! Any help or even suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't insist on using a hex *string* then the easiest solution
would be to create the data from an array with hex *integer values:*

```
let bytes : [UInt8] = [ 0x52, 0x13, 0x00, 0x56, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAA ]
let data = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)
```

And even easier in **Swift 3:**

```
let bytes : [UInt8] = [ 0x52, 0x13, 0x00, 0x56, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAA ]
let data = Data(bytes:bytes)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great and has solved my problem! :) Many thanks!

Comment: how can i dynamically create hex integer value

Comment: @NexMishra: Sorry, I don't understand your question. `bytes` is just an array of numbers.

Comment: let say i have a string which is 0x0018 i want to store this in integer, i want to store 0x0018 in int not 24 as this hexadecimal represents 24 as its value